# How to enable automatic updates (all) on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: updates, kubuntu, discover-software-center

I would like that Discover in my Kubuntu fully and automatically installs all updates in the background. I looked into Muon and set the opion active: "Install security without confirmation". I set everthing there to automatic what was possible. But I get still (security) updates in Discover and I have always to confirm the installation. I don't want to confirm again and again - I want to be always up to date. How can I do it? And why is the setting in Muon not effective?

Btw: I also noted that there is no Live Patch in Kubuntu. This option is not in the "software sources". It was in Ubuntu. I am wondering why not in Kubuntu?